# How to access the TYPO3 settings in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, typo3

In my project we're using TYPO3. We're getting some data from the backend and they're assigned as follows in the html page itself.

```
var items = {};
items.item1 = {settings.item1};
items.item2 = {settings.item2};
items.item3 = {settings.item3};
```

and then the values are being assigned to the buttons. Those values will be sent back to the JS when an action has triggered. The `{settings.item*}` comes from the TYPO3 backend. What I wanted to know is how can I add the above code block in a separate JS file rather than adding it in the HTML page. When I tried adding it directly, it doesn't work as the `{settings.item*}` comes from TYPO3

Thanks

Comment: Can you please provide us the current Typoscript or PHP which writes those values to HTML in the frontend?

Answer (score 0):

You have to pick up your settings from the HTML since this is what TYPO3 will render for you. but you could rather make use of the data-attributes of HTML, e.g.

You could also render the whole `{settings}` array as a JSON string into a data-attribute and pick that up with your JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

You can use javascript on html file (templates , partial , layouts )

You need to add javascript code between the

Syntax:
`<![CDATA[` *javascript code* `]]>` **TYPO3 Code** `<![CDATA[` *javascript code* `]]>`

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<![CDATA[
{
 var items = {};
 items.item1 = ]]>{settings.item1}<![CDATA[;
 items.item2 = ]]>{settings.item2}<![CDATA[;
 items.item3 = ]]>{settings.item3}<![CDATA[;
 ]]>
 </script>
```

Thanks

I hope it helps !!

Answer (score 0):

Can you define the context more precisely? Where are the settings defined, inside of TypoScript, Flexform, PHP (Extensionmanager)?

If you have settings defined in TypoScript you can use:

```
page.inlineSettings {
    setting1 = Hello
    setting2 = GoOnTop
}
```

To make them available in JavaScript as:

```
TYPO3.settings = {"TS":{"setting1":"Hello","setting2":"GoOnTop"}};
```

See: https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TyposcriptReference/Setup/Page/Index.html#inlinesettings

Perhaps this will be removed in future versions as it's purpose is usage via ExtJS. Also it's not possible to use stdWrap and such.

Another, more flexible, way is using

```
page.jsInline {
    10 = TEXT
    10.stdWrap.dataWrap = var pageId = {TSFE:id};
}
```

This allows you to use full TypoScript like TEXT, dataWrap, etc.

See: https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TyposcriptReference/Setup/Page/Index.html#jsinline

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't write JavaScript from PHP just for some configuration. I would store them in data-attributes of a DOM element and grab it via JavaScript. Maybe this is also an option for you.